# Copying to existing set of destination file/directory using java.nio package results in java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, io, nio

I am attempting to copy one file to another location using Java NIO API. When I run below code I get `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException`.

```
public static void copyFileUsingNio(File sourceFile, String destnationFilePath) {
  try {   
    if (sourceFile != null && destnationFilePath != null) {
      java.nio.file.Path sourcePath = sourceFile.toPath();
      java.nio.file.Path destinationPath = java.nio.file.Paths.get(destnationFilePath);

      if (!java.nio.file.Files.exists(destinationPath)) {
        java.nio.file.Path parent = destinationPath.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
          java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(destinationPath.getParent());
          java.nio.file.Files.createFile(destinationPath);    
        }
        destinationPath = java.nio.file.Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
      } else {
        destinationPath = java.nio.file.Files.copy(
            sourcePath, destinationPath,
            java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
      }
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

StackTrace :

> java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException :
>   C:\Users\guest\Desktop\Files\desttest.txt
>
> at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(Unknown Source) 
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source) 
>   at com.filetest.copyFileUsingNio(TestFile.java:110)

Here `destnationFilePath` is **C:/Users/guest/Desktop/Files/desttest.txt**. Also if file already exists then I need to replace it else copy the file.
Please advice me.

Comment: 1) Don't call `createFile()`. There is no need. 2) Why have variable `parent` if you don't really use it? 3) Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: @ Andreas, Please check my updated question with stacktrace. I will create directory if parent exists. If i remove createFile its working.

Comment: You changed the code, removing `REPLACE_EXISTING` from one of the `copy()` calls. If you explicitly call `createFile()`, you know the file will then exist, so why did you remove `REPLACE_EXISTING` from the `copy()` operation. It's then *guaranteed* to throw that exception: `FileAlreadyExistsException`. Which part of **File Already Exists** is confusing you, given that you just created it?

Comment: @ Andreas, I removed because there is no need to force REPLACE_EXISTING since that is new file. If file exists then else block will force REPLACE_EXISTING. sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you create the file yourself and then call `copy()`, `copy()` will *fail* unless you use `REPLACE_EXISTING`. But the real point is to let `copy()` create or replace the file itself, not try to out-think it.

Comment: But you just created the file with `createFile()`, two lines above. At the time `Files.copy()` executes, there is no such thing as "new", only "exists" or "not exists". Doesn't matter that file has only existed for one millisecond.

Comment: @ EJP & Andreas, i have understood and corrected my mistake. I don't know why they are devoting my question. if no one is doing any mistake then SO is no need.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!java.nio.file.Files.exists(destinationPath)) {
    java.nio.file.Path parent = destinationPath.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(destinationPath.getParent());
        java.nio.file.Files.createFile(destinationPath);    
    }
    destinationPath = java.nio.file.Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
} else {
    destinationPath = java.nio.file.Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

You don't need the `exists()` call, or the `createFile()` call, and you don't need the alternative calls to `copy()`.

```
Path parent = destinationPath.getParent();
if (parent != null && !Files.exists(parent)) {
    Files.createDirectories(parent);
}
destinationPath = Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas says, there's no need to call `.createFile()` - the [`copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) operation will create the destination file for you as part of copying it.

As the `.copy()` docs note:

> By default, the copy fails if the target file already exists

This is the cause of `FileAlreadyExistsException` failure you're seeing.

But you don't actually even need an existence check at all if you use the correct options when `copy()`-ing - as the documentation notes [`StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#REPLACE_EXISTING) indicates an existing destination file should be overwritten, rather than cause the operation to fail.

Essentially the only thing you need to do is ensure the parent directory exists (with `Files.createDirectories()` as you're doing), then `copy(source, destination, REPLACE_EXISTING)` will do exactly what you need.

Comment: You don't need to delete the destination if it exists, any more than you need to create it if it doesn't. All that is required is ensuring the *parent directory* exists.

Comment: @EJP right, I was alluding to `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` at the bottom of my answer :)

Comment: He already has that in his code. No need for subtle hints about it.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'd missed that since it overflowed the width of the window.

Comment: You're still not getting it. Your answer says 'you need to check whether the file exists', when he doesn't, and you go on to say so yourself. You're just adding to the confusion here.

Comment: I'm just trying to help work through the issue so OP understands what's going wrong. Without `REPLACE_EXISTING` you need to do an existence-check (like the check in OP's code) due to `.copy()`'s default behavior. Properly using `REPLACE_EXISTING` then eliminates that need. Nevertheless point taken, I've tried to make my intent clearer.

Comment: The OP *started* by using REPLACE_EXISTING in one case, so why are you now talking about not using it?

Comment: The exception they're running into, `FileAlreadyExistsException`, is only possible if you don't use `REPLACE_EXISTING`. Therefore I'm trying to first explain the cause of the exception (incorrectly creating a file then using `.copy()`'s default behavior) before suggesting using `REPLACE_EXISTING`.